# how to create and printing label from our application using FedEx api in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, fedex

We have gone through the Fed Ex website for API service but we could not found any suitable API web service which can help us to implement create and print a label  functionality in our application.  So please  provide in detail how to integrate  create and print label functionality in our application using your FedEx API or  Web service.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. 
While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, 
they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. 
A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, 
example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). 
The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for an asp.net client that integrates with the FedEx API, you can check out this GitHub project - https://github.com/aldenquimby/easypost-dotnet

It's an open client library that integrates with [EasyPost](http://easypost.com?r=soanswer), a shipping API that would allow you to use FedEx.

Otherwise, if you've only gone through the FedEx website, you may want to sign up here to get your FedEx API key (should only take a few weeks) - http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/